# Convergence of Recurrent Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u_0\gt 0$ be a real number and let $a_n$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers. Define the sequence $u_n$ by:

$$u_{n+1} = u_n + \frac{a_n}{u_n}$$

Show that $u_n$ is convergent if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\lt \infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you state its source, show any work you have done, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $(u_n)$ is monotonically increasing and therefore convergent
if and only if it is bounded above.

We have
$$
  (u_{n+1} - u_n)u_0 < (u_{n+1} - u_n) u_n = a_n =  u_{n+1} u_n - u_n^2  < u_{n+1}^2 - u_n^2 \, .
$$

It follows that (telescoping sums)
$$
 (u_N - u_0)u_0 < \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n < u_N^2 - u_0^2 \, ,
$$
therefore the convergence of $(u_n)$ implies the convergence
of  $\sum a_n$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is fairly straightforward: The $u(n)$ are clearly increasing so all $u(n)$ are less than or equal to $u(0) + (1/u(0))\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)$. Thus if $\sum a(n)$ converges to a finite limit, then so does $u(n)$ (because $u(n)$ is a monotonic bounded sequence, hence convergent by theorem).